# Why "have this habit of" instead of "have a habit of"?

Tags: grammar, articles, demonstrative

> If someone's rambling on, I have **this** habit of saying 'And your point is?'.
>
> I have **this** habit of talking to myself.
>
> I have **this** habit of not being able to control my facial expressions when someone says something stupid or annoying from Instagram tagged as Meme.

Why has *this* been used [instead of *a*](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/have-a-habit-of-doing-something) or *the*? Is this usage of *this* generalizable? It looks as if *this* acts as an article here.

Comment: Note that *I have* ***a*** *habit of* is also common.

Comment: @JasonBassford Perhaps *have a habit of* is more common. Longman Dictionary contains it as an entry: https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/have-a-habit-of-doing-something

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the use of **this** here is generalisable. You can say:

> You see, I have this cup. It's my favourite cup.

It's a colloquial usage to show some familiarity with the object of the sentence.

Comment: +1 for "show...familiarity".  *There's this little restaurant we go to on the island. It has really good Key Lime pie.*